# SVN for resource-heavy project - code & resources in separate repository?

Tags: svn

I read an interesting SO discussion on putting separate projects in their own repos or not. But my question is about a single project, which has code, and then a lot of artwork - hundreds of Mb at least. At a simple usability level, it's annoying that telling a developer to "go get a working copy" means waiting ages for the whole art section to download. And I'm concerned this is going to be a big bloat when we use branches more.

Conceptually it's one project. But when I've worked with repos which expect me to individually get working copies of several sub-directories, things seem to screw up somehow. Through user error most likely, but the whole point is to make suer errors less easy to make!

Another problem I seem to remember is setting per-user permissions on sub-directories won't let people simply get a working copy of the repo, with the unauthorized folders omitted. Instead, it just breaks... I don't really want my artists able to change (or even see) code.

Comment: I already did. Not that it's any of your business, to be honest. Help if you want to help, not to get meaningless points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd still put the into one repository, to allow you to branch and merge this project centrally. Especially when tagging release, you'd have to tag in 2 repositories when releasing.

You could do a structure like this:

```
/svn/repository/trunk/src
/svn/repository/trunk/artwork
```

And tell developers to only checkout `src`, art people checkout `artwork`, and when branching, you can branch/tag `trunk`

Answer (score 1):

You could also go with one repo but store the resources in a separate tree. I.e., just move the usual layout

```
trunk/
branches/
tags/
```

below a new folder you call `code` or something like that, and store the resources in a folder `artwork`. I.e. create a folder structure like this

```
code/
    trunk/
    branches/
    tags/
resources/
    trunk/
    branches/
    tags/
```

A developer usually only wants to get the code trunk, and as he usually gets `trunk` in the first layout he just needs to get `code/trunk` in the second layout instead. I haven't tried this, but if the code itself relies on resources you might be able to pull them via `svn:externals`.

Comment: This means that once you branch or tag, you have to branch/tag both, and then edit the externals to use the branch or tag.

Comment: I agree about the branch/tag to be done twice, but that is easy to script and can be automated.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a separate repo for resources, and just refer to it with an svn:external property, avoiding all those user errors.

Comment: This means that once you branch or tag, your external is still a moving target. You have to branch/tag and then *edit* the external to use a fixed revision or its own branch/tag to get this right

Answer (score 0):

It looks like [compressing your binary files](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-svnbins.html) can reduce the amount of time it takes to import and export such data from a Subversion repository.

Comment: Not binary files. Art resources, which are often not that compressible - PNGs don't really compress for instance, neither do video files. It's a good thing to do, but doesn't really solve the problem.